# HTML tag to simply give a text an id

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Is there a html tag to simply give a text an id/class?
Let's say I have the text "email" in front of an `input` tag, and i want to change the text (with js) on button click. I'd need an id... `p` would kick the input on a new line (which i don't want) and `font` is a bit outdated.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element for describing a subsequent `input` tag should be a `label` tag, which has to have a `for` attribute that contains the name of the corresponding `input` tag. You can therefore select that element as a label with a particular attribute.

Example

```
<label for="email">Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" />
```

and to select it and change its text:

```
jQuery('label[for=email]').text('your new label text');
```

Note that this is the *only* solution (for labeling inputs) which also meets accessibility standards.

You can style it any way you want using CSS.

Answer (score 4):

The `<span>` element is a generic (i.e. it has no associated semantics) inline element that can be used for marking some content for access via CSS / JS / etc.

However, "the text 'email' in front of an input" sounds very much like a [`<label>` element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/) so you should probably use that instead.

Answer (score 3):

`<span id="..." class="..."></span>` is the element you are looking for, it stays completly inline and doesn't move any content, but still is accessible through JavaScript.